# Showing Recent Issues Unable to load contents of file list:

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, syntax-error, cocoapods

[Anyone know how to fix these errors? 
Showing Recent Issues
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-CurryFinder/Pods-CurryFinder-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyDF4.jpg)

Comment: You need to explain more about how you got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've made some manual changes to your targets.
Try `pod install` in the terminal in order to add necessary configuration files to the project. If it doesn't help, first delete *Pods* folder and execute `pod install` in the terminal for your project directory. Also double check your pod file.